# How can I write this function signature in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, recursive-type

I have a minimal reproduction of a recursive type problem I've encountered.  Here's some typescript.

```
type Cloneable = string | number | Cloneable[];

function clone<T extends Cloneable>(arg: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(arg)) return arg.map(e => clone(e));
    else return arg;
}
```

> Type 'Cloneable[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'Cloneable[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Cloneable'.

My intent is that return type of `clone` should be identical to its argument.  In practice, it's going to involve some proxy stuff, but that's not relevant here.  Is there a way I can type this correctly without resorting to `any`?

Comment: You have to cast `as T` or `as any as T`, TS can't infer that

Comment:  https://kelsny.github.io/typescript/conditional-type-abuse

Answer (score 1):

To explain the error message, let's merely declare the type of your `clone` function without bothering to define it:

```
type Cloneable = string | number | Cloneable[];

declare function clone<T extends Cloneable>(arg: T): T;
```

Here's an example of something that conforms to `Cloneable`, because it is an array containing strings and numbers, but it also happens to have an extra function attached to it:

```
const test = Object.assign(["dolphin", 42], {
    petunias() {
        console.log("Oh no, not again.");
    } 
});
```

Sure enough, we can pass it to `clone`:

```
const cloneTest = clone(test);
```

And TS now believes the type of `cloneTest` will be the complete type, so in your editor you'll see this pop-up:

```
const cloneTest: (string | number)[] & {
    petunias(): void;
}
```

Does your implementation ensure that the returned clone reproduces any extra bells and whistles that any random subtype of `T` might have? No. And what would it mean, in general terms, to clone such things? How do you ensure a deep clone of functions and properties that you have no understanding of?

In other words, TS is pointing out the truth: your function cannot do what it claims to do.

Comment: "your function cannot do what it claims to do." 

I believe the identity function would do it.  So it's not impossible from a type system standpoint.  

The function I'm writing does have a behavior.  In my view, it would be closer to "correct" to use `T`.  As it stands, I'm asserting `any` in the troublesome spots.  That seems worse to me.